# Searching chat history for two consecutive double quotes yields server error

Tags: bug, chat, chat-search

If you search in the chat history for something with two double quotes, something bad will happen. For example, try [searching](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search) for `""abc""`.

[image: Screenshot demonstrating the problem]

Comment: And why, exactly, would you be doing this in the first place?

Comment: @TheEstablishment There is something with two double quotes in the chat history and I need to find it.

Comment: ["Something bad happened"](http://i.imgur.com/Zru7H.png)... no kidding ;)

Comment: You could escape the quotation marks, but [it doesn't seem to consider them when searching](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%5C%22%5C%22abc%5C%22%5C%22%22&user=&room=).

Comment: (@Mat, thanks for [teaching me something](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consecutive)! Just as you seem to take an interest in the matter: letting Google tell what's most *used*, "[subsequent characters](https://www.google.nl/search?q=%22subsequent+characters%22)" is used about as often as "[consecutive characters](https://www.google.nl/search?q=%22consecutive+characters%22)". That proves nothing, I know, but it seems [subsequent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsequent) *can* be used for order (without referring to time) too? Still then, consecutive might be better.)

Comment: @Arjan: that's more of a question for english.SE :) In my understanding, "subsequent" needs something to be subsequent to. "Two consecutive `/` denote the start of a comment, subsequent chars are ignored until end of line" - or something like that. But I may very well be wrong, I'm not a native speaker.